There is some space inside the Bottom Navigation View below the items in XML and Kotlin in Android Studio
I created a bottom bar using BottomNavigationView and used a menu file to display items inside it. When I set the height of the BottomNavigationView to wrap_content, it displayed with some space inside the view, below the items, on my physical device. Additionally, the text of the last item (on the right side) is shrunk with ellipsis (dots). I would like to fix these issues. I will add the related code and a screenshot of the physical device.
Is there any alternative way to do this?
I want my bottom bar to be below my RecyclerView.
my activity xml:
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Main">

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/feedcycle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:foregroundGravity="left" />


    <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bnv"
        style="@style/Widget.Material3.BottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#E91E63"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
        app:menu="@menu/bottomaction" />

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>


my menu xml code :
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Videos"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_all_out_24"
        android:title="Videos" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Search"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_abc_24"
        android:title="Search" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Feed"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_adjust_24"
        android:title="Feed" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/Community"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_airplay_24"
        android:title="Community" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/Recommendation"
        android:icon="@drawable/baseline_all_out_24"
        android:title="Recommendation" />

</menu>


This are my code and i'll provide my physical device screenshot
physical device
and when i add 0 dp or set 75 or 85 dp to bottom bar height it displays like this
changes with height 
i'm unable to figure what's the problem.

try adding either app:contentInsetStart="0dp" or app:contentInsetEnd="0dp" to the BottomNavigationView
